# Running the "exec" command in Jenkins "Execute Shell"

Tags: c++, linux, bash, c++11, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on a Linux host. I'm automating the build of a C++ application. In order to build the application I need to use the 4.7 version of g++ which includes support for c++11. In order to use this version of g++ I run the following command at a command prompt:

```
exec /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
```

So I created a "Execute shell" build step and put the following commands, which properly builds the C++ application on the command prompt:

```
exec /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
libtoolize
autoreconf --force --install
./configure --prefix=/home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/project
make
make install
cd procs
./makem.sh /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/project
```

The problem is that Jenkins will not run any of the commands after the "exec /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash" command, but instead just runs the "exec" command, terminates and marks the build as successful.

Any ideas on how I can re-structure the above so that Jenkins will run all the commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At the begining of your "Execute shell" script, execute `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/enable` to enable the devtoolet "inside" of your shell.

Which gives:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-1.1/enable
libtoolize
autoreconf --force --install
./configure --prefix=/home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/project
make
make install
cd procs
./makem.sh /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/project
```

Comment: Works with the v2 too ;-) `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to look up what [scl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scl) actually does.

```
Examples

scl enable example 'less --version'
    runs command 'less --version' in the environment with collection 'example' enabled
scl enable foo bar bash
    runs bash instance with foo and bar Software Collections enabled
```

So what you are doing is running a bash shell. I guess, that the bash shell returns immediately, since you are in non-interactive mode. `exec` runs the the command within the shell without creating a new shell. That means if the newly opened bash ends it also ends your shell prematurely. I would suggest to put all your build steps into a bash script (e.g. run_my_build.sh) and call it in the following way.

```
exec /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-1.1 run_my_build.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing normally works in "find" commands, but may work here. Rather than running two, or three processes, you run one "sh" that executes multiple things, like this:

exec sh -c "thing1; thing2; thing3"

If you require each step to succeed before the next step, replace the semi-colons with double ampersands:

exec sh -c "thing1 && thing2 && thing3"

I have no idea which of your steps you wish to run together, so I am hoping you can adapt the concept to fit your needs.

Or you can put the whole lot into a script and exec that.

Comment: Hey Mark: I had tried doing "&&" however it still fails due to the fact that when I run the "exec /usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash" I believe a separate shell is spawned, but it would still invoke the 4.4 version of GCC rather than the 4.7. What I've done instead is just inject the PATH variable like this:

PATH=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin:$PATH

This essentially would put the 4.7 g++ executable first before the 4.4, and it only applies this to the project. I'm not sure it's the best solution, but it meets what I was trying to do.